Why the orthogonal projection give minimal?
Given the data $ \vec{x}=(-2,-1,1,2) )$ and $( y=(1,1,-1,1) )$. Use an orthogonal projection to determine the coefficients $( a_{0}, a_{1}, a_{2} )$ of the quadratic polynomial function
$
\begin{aligned}
f: \mathbb{R} & \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
x & \mapsto a_{0}+a_{1} x+a_{2} x^{2}
\end{aligned}
such that the value
$
\sum_{i=1}^{4}\left(f\left(x_{i}\right)-y_{i}\right)^{2}
$
is minimal. Explain why the solution is uniquely determined.
i have calculated this by finding $A^tAa=A^ty$
and di could also do it by finding Gram matrix by
$g_i,_{j}$ = $ \sum_{i=1}^4v_0\left(x_{i}\right)v_0\left(x_{i}\right) $
for $v_0(x)=1 $,  $v_1(x)=x $  ,  $v_2(x)=x^2$  as basis.
so i got matrix G from both way i mentioned ,and then solved $Ga=b$
and i got a which's orthogonal projection , and since the matrix regular the solution will be unique .
my problem is why is even what i did correct. i mean i did only imitate the given example, and i do not know why what i calculated is minimal in the first place, i get that it's unique since the matrix is regular, but why is it minimal what i calculated ?

It is a classical property in Euclidean geometry that the closest point in a given subspace $S$ to a given point $p$ is the orthogonal projection image of $p$ onto $p$ (this is even true if $S$ is an affine subspace, obtained by translation of a vector subspace). In this case the space is $\Bbb{R}^4$ with the usual Euclidean structure (scalar product), the point $p$ is $(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)$, and the subspace $S$ is the image of $\Bbb{R}^3$ under the (injective) linear map $m:\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}^4$ given by $m:(a_0,a_1,a_2)\mapsto(a_0+a_1x_i+a_2x_i^2)_{i=1,2,3,4}$ (the important point to note is that, for each $i$, the expression in parenthesis is linear in $(a_0,a_1,a_2)$; that it is not linear in $x_i$ is irrelevant). Then the orthogonal projection of $p$ onto $S$ can by definition be written as $m((a,b,c))$, and by injectivity of $m$ the triple $(a,b,c)$ is unique.
